# Intent filter no working as expected

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have inside manifest to start DummyActivity on clicking a link.

```
    <intent-filter android:label="Dummy Stuff">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/services/login/reset.html"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When I click the link that matches the pattern, it opens the app every time, but sometimes it goes to DummyActivity and sometimes to whatever Activity it was previously there. Any idea?

Also note that I am clicking on a dynamic link and using firebase to handle the deep link. Also note that even in instances when it show another activity, I have checked with debugger that DummyActivity does not open at all. So we can eliminate the case of DummyActivity redirecting it to another one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following fixed the issue:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
```

So the intent filter looks like:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="example.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can't do that. I am handling other paths for other activities.